# Запятая перед фразой «и это не предел»

Tags: запятые

Нужно ли ставить запятую перед фразой «и это не предел»? К примеру, в следующих случаях:

> 20 метров(,) и это не предел.

> Он забрался на гору Вопроско(,) и это не предел.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Универсальным вариантом будет постановка запятых:

**20 метров, и это не предел.**

**Он забрался на гору Вопроско, и это не предел.**

Если необходима более длинная пауза, можно поставить тире, точку или многоточие.

Здесь мы имеем дело с присоединительными предложениями, образованными с помощью союза "и". Подробно про это можно почитать у [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=120).

> Перед присоединительной конструкцией могут стоять следующие знаки препинания:
>
> 1. запятая: *Некогда он служил в гусарах, и даже счастливо (П.);*
> 2. тире: *Дело мы делаем великое и сделали уже немало, а недостатки
>    есть — и серьёзные (Чак.);*
> 3. точка: *Когда мы говорим о слезах радости, с которыми встречает
>    Красную Армию население освобождённых городов, это может показаться
>    формулой. Но доктор Коровина плакала от радости. И Бабкин. И старый
>    священник Говоров. И тысячи, тысячи людей (Эр.),*
> 4. многоточие: *Страшно признаться, но я хочу, чтоб этот человек знал,
>    что она мне как песня… И, должно быть, последняя (Пог.).*

Так что в зависимости от стилистики текста и интонационных пауз возможна постановка различных знаков препинания.

[Поиск по Нацкорпусу](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%B8%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB) показывает, что чаще всего конструкцию "и это не предел" отделяют либо запятой, либо точкой. Например,

**На сегодняшний день синтезированы элементы седьмого периода до 118-го включительно, и это не предел.**

**Они уже сейчас на историческом минимуме ― 110 долларов за тонну, если говорить о коксующемся угле. И это не предел.**

Comment: Спасибо, что отвечаете, мне понравился ваш ответ. Если позволите, маленькое замечание. В начале ответа лучше дать сам ответ (причем близкий по форме к вопросу),  который вы поместили после правил.  Это такой принцип современного информативного стиля: сначала вывод, а потом текст.  После ссылки на правило можно изложить его суть, но желательно в сокращенном виде и с небольшим количеством примеров, а весь текст правила автор вопроса может прочитать сам. Удачи вам!

Comment: @Sharon, спасибо за комментарий. Поправил ответ.